# Apache Directory partition empty after restart

Tags: apacheds

Our ApacheDS server had an unexpected restart, and after the restart it shows the custom partition we added for our company as empty.

However when looking on the server I can still see the master.db files etc which seem to contain all the user and group information.

What can we do to restore this information in ApacheDS?